# How do I import a matrix into my matlab script code

Tags: matlab, matrix, import

A friend emailed me a file (.mat) which includes quite a large matrix (200x200). I need to take this matrix and insert it into my code which is a separate file (.m)
How can I do this? 
Thank you

Comment: recommending reposting this with `matlab` tag to get some feedback!

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to have the literal matrix in your source-code? You do not want to simply have the code load the matrix from the .mat file each time it is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the .mat file in the same diectory as your m file and use load command to load the matrix in a variable.

For example

```
Matrix = load('Example.mat');
```

This will store the matrix from .mat file in the variable Matrix.